# Closed irreducible subset

Tags: gn.general-topology

A nonempty subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called irreducible if, if $A\subset A_{1}\cup A_{2}$ and $A_{1}, A_{2}$ are closed subsets of $X$, then $A\subset A_{1}$ or $A\subset A_{2}$. We know that in a Hausdorff space $X$ a closed subset is irreducible if and only if it is a singleton.

Questions: When is a closed subset of a $T_{1}$-space irreducible? Is there an equivalent condition for it?

Comment: Irreducible requires nonempty.

Comment: I don't think that there is an equivalent condition. After all, every affine variety (in the classical sense, i.e. without generic points) is $T_1$ and there no equivalent purely topological condition is known.

Comment: MArtin: topology of schemas is generally $T_0$ (sobre space). ANyway a topological space  is $T_0$ iff for $x \neq y$ then $x\not\in cl(${y} or $y\not\in cl(${x}. A schema is $T_1$ iff is $T_2$ . In a $T_1$ space (i.e. such tath any singleton is closed) the only irreducible close set are the singleton. 

Comment: @Buschi Sergio: perhaps you meant to say in your last sentence that *sober* $T_1$ spaces have the property that closed irreducible subsets are singletons. Also, is your second sentence really true? Do you have a reference? 

Comment: I meant third sentence about $T_2$. 

Comment: You right $T_1\not\Rightarrow\ sober$. In sober spaces: $T_1 \Leftrightarrow$  "irreducible component =singletons". Second sentence is equivalent to $cl(x)\neq cl(y)$ iff $x\neq y$ (observe that  $cl(x)=cl(y)\Leftrightarrow x\in cl(y)\wedge cl(x)$) and see Ex.1.5.A p. 71 in  Gen. Topology (Engelking).

A (topol. space of a) schema $X$  is sober (2.1.5 of EGA1,SPringer).
and  it is **Locally** (on affine opens) a Stone space (and then $T_2$):  Johnstone "Stone space" pag. 198, pag. 69. My (previous) third sentence  is false (it imply that a $T_1$ space is sober).

Comment: I mean  ..a Stone space (and then  locally $T_2$)... 

Comment: @Buschi Sergio: Yeah, I just meant a reference for your third sentence, which you now acknowledge was false. I didn't need references for the rest, but thanks. By the way, I added to my earlier answer to your question on closed structures that you asked a few days ago. 

Comment: My friend Maurizio Porta give me (by Email) a example about a $T_1$ schema, that isn't $T_2$: let $X$ the schema of infinite numerable product of a field, the topology is $T_1$ and cofinite, but no $T_2$  

Comment: Dear friends, I thank of your answers. A topological space is $T_{1}$ if and only if any single point is closed. For example an ifinite set $X$ with cofinite topology (open sets are stes which complements are finite) is a $T_{1}$-space which is not $T_{2}$-space.